# Kafka log compaction and event sourcing

Tags: apache-kafka, event-sourcing

I am using kafka as event-store. Although events should never be deleted, I want to know the best strategy to delete specific events from kafka in cases where the logs grow too much. The candidate events to clean would be e.g. events owning to deleted aggregates, events that were consider initially but are not needed, etc.

1. Kafka implements a log compaction strategy based on a key. Is it possible to use it somehow to delete some events?
2. Is there any other way to automatically delete events owning to a specific aggregate?

Thank you

Comment: One of the points of event sourcing is to keep the complete a complete audit log of your system, one more is to run data analysis on everything, including things that happened in the past. Deliberately removing events for inactive aggregates inevitable disable both of these options without any way to get back. Storage is cheap now days, unlkne relevant data, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. Quoting the [documentation on log compaction](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Log+Compaction)

> Compaction also allows from deletes. A message with a key and a null payload will be treated as a delete from the log. This delete marker will cause any prior message with that key to be removed (as would any new message with that key), but delete markers are special in they will themselves be cleaned out of the log after a period of time. The point in time at which deletes are no longer retained is given above.

2. No, I think that using a key to identify the messages from a particular aggregate is your best option here.

Comment: "The point in time at which deletes are no longer retained is given above" ... amusingly enough the page the link refers to has been deleted :)